# Extracting parenthesis with a specific format with Python

Tags: python, regex

I am fairly new to python so I apologies if this is quite a novice question, but I am trying to extract text from parentheses that has specific format from a raw text file. 
I have tried this with regular expressions, but please let me know if their is a better method.

To show what I want to do by example:

```
s = "Testing (Stackoverflow, 2013). Testing (again) (Stackoverflow, 1999)"
```

From this string I want a result something like:

```
['(Stackoverflow, 2013)', '(Stackoverflow, 1999)']
```

The regular expression I have tried so far is

```
"(\(.+[,] [0-9]{4}\))"
```

in conjunction with re.findall(), however this only gives me the result:

```
['(Stackoverflow, 2013). Testing (again) (Stackoverflow, 1999)']
```

So, as you may have guessed, I am trying to extract the bibliographic references from a .txt file. But I don't want to extract anything that happens to be in parentheses that is not a bibliographic reference.

Again, I apologies if this is novice, and again if there is a question like this out there already. I have searched, but no luck as yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you will have **no** nested brackets, you could use something like so: `(\([^()]+?, [0-9]{4}\))`. This will match any non bracket character which is within a set of parenthesis which is followed by a comma, a white space four digits and a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Ah excellent. Thank-you for the explanation! And yes there will be no nested parentheses. However, how would that change your response?

Comment: @SamPassmore: Glad it worked out for you. It would change because of this: `[^()]`. This asks the engine to not match any parenthesis which are already enclosed in another set of parenthesis, so changes would need to be made to cater for nesting.

Answer (score 1):

Using `[^()]` instead of `.`. This will make sure there is no nested ().

```
>>> re.findall("(\([^()]+[,] [0-9]{4}\))", s)
['(Stackoverflow, 2013)', '(Stackoverflow, 1999)']
```

Comment: Thanks! That works excellently, and in my full text file as well. 
Do you mind explaining how this "[^()]+" works?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like `\(\w+,\s+[0-9]{4}\)`. A couple changes from your original:

- Match word characters (letters/numbers/underscores) instead of any character in the source name.
- Match one or more space characters after the comma, instead of limiting yourself to a single literal space.